# How do I know what repositories my git server is serving

Tags: git

I have just been access to a server that someone said is "the git repository"

I have not used git before, but I assume that must mean there are a set of files somewhere that are the "gold copies" that other developers are pulling from when they do their git updates. How do I find what those directories are? How can I determine what the "access url" that folks who wnat to checkout can use?

Thanks

Comment: I would read a tutorial. [Here](http://sixrevisions.com/resources/git-tutorials-beginners/) a list of 10 good tutorials. If you're used to a VCS like SVN, forget everything you know, git is completely different.

Comment: ok thanks for the comments. I will close this out and repost when I have a more specific issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note that Git, as well as other DVCSes, use slightly different concepts than centralized SVN or CVS systems. In particular, the normal usage is not to "check out" but to **clone** a repository, downloading its complete history instead of just the head – in other words, the fact that your server has "gold copies" is only political, and any clone can be used as a "gold copy" easily. This is not very important right now, but worth remembering nevertheless, in particular when you forget to do backups...*

Find out what software was used to set up the server – was it Gitolite, Gitosis, or just a custom ssh + git-daemon setup?

Gitolite and Gitosis use a central configuration file and keep everything in the home directory of an account named `git`. Run `cd ~git`, look for repositories there. The URLs will likely be `git://<server>/<repository>.git` for public access and `git@<server>:<repository>.git` for pushing over SSH. Both Gitosis and Gitolite have separate management tools – try the `gitolite` command.

If no such account exists in system, or if it does not contain the "admin" repository, check if anything is listening on port 9418, the Git smart protocol port; if it's `git-daemon`, check its command line with `ps www <pid>`. The public URLs will still start with `git://<server>/`, but the rest depends on git-daemon's command-line options; it may or may not require the full filesystem path, it may or may not support "vhosts"; it may or may not have `~username/path/repo.git` style userdirs enabled. The SSH addresses might be `<username>@<server>:</path/to/repo>.git`; note that SSH always works even without git-daemon.

The server might also have a web interface set up (cgit or gitweb), which should list all configured repositories. Try accessing it over a web browser. Look in `/etc` for configuration of gitweb / cgit.

A useful command is `git ls-remote <url>`, which can show a quick summary of a repository without cloning it. This way you can check if URLs are valid.